# Post requests not firing on user form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a react blog application with a form to submit a blog post. I have set up a server, routes, a model, and controllers for the fetch requests, and they all work when I use postman, but for some reason when I try to implement the post request on the submit button of the form, nothing gets sent to the database. Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Here is the react code for the form

```
import React from 'react'
import fireIconImage from '../images/fireIcon.png'
import FireIcon from './FireIcon'


export default function BlogPostForm () {
    const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({ flaire: '', title: '', text: '', fireLevel: ''});
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = React.useState();
    const [isLit, setIsLit] = React.useState();

    function changeFlaire(event) {
        const selectedFlaire = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, flaire: selectedFlaire });
    }

    function changeTitle(event) {
        const title = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, title: title });
    }

    function changeText(event) {
        const text = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, text: text });
    }

    function handleMouseOver(e) {
        setIsHovered(e.target.id);
    }

    function handleMouseLeave(e) {
        setIsHovered();
    }

    function handleFireIconClick(e) {
        setIsLit(e.target.id);
    }

    function handleFireIconClass(fireLevel) {
        const classNames = ['fireIcon']
            classNames.push(`fireIcon${fireLevel}`)
            if (isHovered >= fireLevel) {
                classNames.push('isHeld')
            }
            if (isLit >= fireLevel) {
                classNames.push('isLit')
            }
        return classNames.join(' ');
        
    }

    function submitForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = formState;
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/', options);
    }




    const fireIconsArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fireIconsArray.push(
            <FireIcon 
                onClick={handleFireIconClick}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
                className={handleFireIconClass(i+1)}
                src={fireIconImage}
                alt="fire icon"
                id={i+1}
                key={i+1}
            />
        )
    }

    
    return (
        <form className="postForm">
            <h1 className="postFormHeader">Create a blog post!</h1>        
                <select
                    required
                    className="flaireSelect" 
                    value={formState.flaire}
                    onChange={changeFlaire}>
                        <option disabled={true} value="">Choose a flaire</option>
                        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
                        <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
                        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                        <option value="REACT">REACT</option>
                        <option value="BACKEND">BACKEND</option>
                </select>
                <input
                    value={formState.title}
                    onChange={changeTitle}
                    className="titleBox"
                    placeholder="title"
                    type="text"
                    id="title"
                    name="title"
                />
                <textarea
                    value={formState.text}
                    onChange={changeText}
                    className="textBox"
                    placeholder="text"
                    type="text"
                    id="blogPost"
                    name="blogPost"
                />
                <div className="fireIconContainer">
                    {fireIconsArray}
                </div>  
                <div className="blogPostFormButtonContainer">
                    <button className="blogPostSubmit" type="submit" onClick={submitForm}>SUBMIT</button>
                    <button className="blogPostCancel" type="submit">CANCEL</button>
                </div>

        </form>
    )
}
```

Here is the controller code

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const Post = require('../models/postModel')


//Set post
//route: POST /api/posts/id
//access: Private
const setPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.title) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('Please add a title')
    }

    const post = await Post.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        flaire: req.body.flaire,
        postText: req.body.text,
        fireLevel: req.body.fireLevel,
    })

    console.log(post)

    res.status(200).json(post)
})
```

Here are the routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const {getPosts, setPost, updatePost, deletePost} = require('../controllers/postController')

//this tells which url route to use when a post and get request is made
router.route('/').get(getPosts).post(setPost)
//this tells which url route to use when a delete or put request is made
router.route('/:id').delete(deletePost).put(updatePost)
```

here is the server

```
const express = require ('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const port = 8000 //process.env.PORT//
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const cors = require("cors")
const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')


//connect the database to the server//
connectDB()


//initialize the app as express object
const app = express()

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}))


//tell the app to accept incoming and outgoing req, res as json
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false})) //?//

//not sure what this does, i think its telling the route it should look for//
app.use('/', require('./routes/postRoutes'))

//make sure the app utulizes the error handler functions//
app.use(errorHandler)

//tell the app what port to listen on
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))

console.log('Hello World')
```

and here is the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a title']
    }, 
    flaire: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select a flaire']
    },
    postText: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a body to your post']
    },
    fireLevel: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please select a fire level']
    }
}, 
    {
    timestamps: true,
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the fireLevel in your state so the form data was incomplete GOOFY

Comment: Other than finding a bug in your own code, this post doesn't really provide much value to a third person. Consider removing the question.

Comment: debatable! @sayandcode